# What is the code used to switch back to a previously running window via Apple's Automator?

Tags: applescript, automator

I created a code that toggles the keyboard viewer in Automator.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    if application "KeyboardViewer" is running then
        quit application "KeyboardViewer"
    else
        activate application "KeyboardViewer"
    end if
    return input
end run
```

However, the Keyboard Viewer becomes the current running window and I cannot instantaneously start typing (I have to switch back to the previous window). Is there a specific code that I can add so that the previous window is highlighted again ?

Answer (score 7):

You could use `launch` instead of `activate`:

```
tell application "KeyboardViewer"
    if running then
        quit
    else
        launch
    end if
end tell
```

If the application wasn't open, `launch` usually opens a new window above other applications but below the frontmost application. Otherwise it just keeps the application on the background. You can use `AXRaise` to raise windows in the second case, but it also makes them look like active windows.

```
launch application "Terminal"
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal"
    perform action "AXRaise" of windows
end tell
```

You could also save the previous application in a variable:

```
set a to path to frontmost application as text
activate application "Terminal"
activate application a
```

If you're moving focus to a background application, you can just activate the frontmost application later:

```
try
    tell application "SystemUIServer"
        display dialog "" default answer ""
    end tell
end try
activate application (path to frontmost application as text)
```

Comment: You have to enable access for assistive devices in the accessibility preferences. AXRaise is not needed for KeyboardViewer, but I tried to make the answer generic.

Answer (score 1):

Try this just after the activate application "KeyboardViewer" line...

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke tab using command down
```

***EDIT***: Since the original post above didn't do it for you then try this. It uses a subroutine I use to get the frontmost running application in cases just like this. Just put this code into the applescript section of your automator action...

```
on run {input, parameters}
    if application "KeyboardViewer" is running then
        quit application "KeyboardViewer"
    else
        set frontAppPath to my getFrontAppPath()
        activate application "KeyboardViewer"
        delay 0.2
        tell application frontAppPath to activate
    end if
    return input
end run

on getFrontAppPath()
    set frontAppPath to (path to frontmost application) as text
    set myPath to (path to me) as text

    if frontAppPath is myPath then
        try
            tell application "Finder" to set bundleID to id of file myPath
            tell application "System Events" to set visible of (first process whose bundle identifier is bundleID) to false

            -- we need to delay because it takes time for the process to hide
            -- I noticed this when running the code as an application from the applescript menu bar item
            set inTime to current date
            repeat
                set frontAppPath to (path to frontmost application) as text
                if frontAppPath is not myPath then exit repeat
                if (current date) - inTime is greater than 1 then exit repeat
            end repeat
        end try
    end if
    return frontAppPath
end getFrontAppPath
```

Comment: This works but the keyboard is now hidden behind the running application window

Comment: I added an "edit" section to my post which should work for you. Good luck.